# Bootstrap NavMenu displays odd Character

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this HTML markup as my NavMenue in a Visual Studio Application

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <img src="Images/OCSOLogo50.jpg"/>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
               
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Default">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Users</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Pretty straight forward and I have used this basic format in several other applications.  For some reason this time it does not render properly.  The Image below is what I am seeing when I run the Ap.[image]

Any idea as to why that odd symbol just to right of the image is showing instead of my expected menu items? If I comment out span tags and the href tags the image is shown without that other object.???

Comment: Does that odd character still show up after a full refresh (ctrl-F5)? I've seen stuff like that before in a similar bootstrap/navmenu setup, but it was never permanent/persistent. If I do a full refresh it is gone, and I could never figure out how to recreate it.

Comment: Try checking HTML that comes before/after the navbar, e.g. your `_Layout.cshtml`.

Comment: Press F12 > Go to Elements tab > Click the arrow button on the extreme top-left corner and then hover your mouse on this odd character. Once you find it in Elements tab, it would now easy to find in your _Layout.cshtml page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all of suggestion the only way I could fix it was to just create a new page.